# Best practise: Sending typed data over TCP

Tags: c++, web-services, sockets, soap, tcp

I want to implement a server which has a few methods from which one accepts an array of two-dimensional points (a struct). I'm wondering if I should implement it as a WebService or as a simple TCP socket.

The target system is C++ running on Debian Linux. As far as my understanding goes, a WebService is based on XML/SOAP and I can use the interface including all its datatypes on any other client system. Contrary, a plain TCP socket is just reading byte arrays. But is there an easy way to achieve kind of strongly typed data transfer with TCP sockets so that I don't need a webserver for running the WebService?

Here a C# example what the interface of the server should look like:

```
public interface IService
{
    void CloseShutter();
    bool WriteFrame(Point[] frame, bool repeat);
    MaintenanceInfo GetMaintenanceInfo();
}

public struct Point
{
    public float X { get; set; }    
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
    public bool Draw { get; set; }
}

public struct MaintenanceInfo
{
    public uint Lifetime { get; set; }
    public bool UsedHours { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any advise.

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an abstraction layer on top of TCP instead of plain sockets has many advantages. Usually those solutions use XML or any comparable human-readable format. The data is then serialized and send over a standard TCP socket. In this way cross-plattform communication (here: C++, objective-C to C#) is achieved and you can use the client/servers as objects in your code.

One of the best solutions I found so far are:

a) [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/): Pro: Easy to set up and just a few lines of auto-generated code. Cons: uses a proprietary data format which is not XML.

b) [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html): Pro: Widely used and based on SOAP/XML WebServices. Cons: Not that easy to learn.

c) [CodeSynthesis XSD/e](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsde/) with [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html): Sending and receiving XML documents (or object that can be transformed from and to XML) using streams with underlying TCP sockets. Pro: Based on sockets, no SOAP/WebService. Cons: More lines of code and more learning necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML-RPC for C++ : http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's exactly what I need. I will have a closer look into that one.

Comment: I gave that a try, but the code was kind of complicated (though I'm mostly into C# code). The communication to other languages (clients) which might be written in objective-c or C# was questionable. That's why I did not choose XML-RPC.

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight way is to use serialization. Take a look at boost::serialization namespace or any other library that do it well. This way you can write serialized objects directly in a tcp stream and get them back on the other side. If you want a human-readable format, serialize them as xml.

Otherwise you can copy the raw structs into your output buffer. You may reverse your struct to respect the network standard endianness. Be also carrefull of the data padding.

Comment: Nice idea, I forgot about that. But how do you manage the three different methods here? You would need some kind of initial command then, or?